# C# AWS SQS request signature does not match the signature provided

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I have a single project that contains classes to communicate with AWS. SQS is the only one that is not working. It is safe to assume that the access and secret keys are valid. I am also able to access this queue elsewhere so i am 100% it exists.

I have created a super basic method and this is failing.

```
var Config = new AmazonSQSConfig() { ServiceURL = "https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/.....etc"};
var Client = new AmazonSQSClient(Config);
SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest() { MessageBody = "Hello", };
SendMessageResponse sendMessageResponse = Client.SendMessage(request);
```

When the final line `Client.SendMessage(request)` runs it throws a 403 exception with the error

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

The code is so basic that i cant see where it could be wrong. The secret and access keys work for all other AWS communication so this cant be the cause and i am 100% sure the queue exists. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This code works - see if you can use it instead:

```
    using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
    {
        client.SendMessage(new SendMessageRequest { QueueUrl = _queueName, MessageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request) });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a really weird one, but i resolved the issue by using the fragmented AWSSDK instead of the complete one. I was using the main sdk from NuGet that contains everything for AWS. I removed this and install the core, s3 and sqs parts of the SDK. The code immediately worked once i did this. No idea why it did this and why it worked for S3 and not SQS, but at least this was a fairly simple fix.